# queries not isolating records

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that runs two different queries. the results includes records that when the second query is run it fails to isolate(drill down) the records of the first query.

I have tried setting up several different queries in order to isolate the records, including trying to combine the queries in hopes of eliminating a recall of the records already filtered out.

```
    Private Sub cmdSearchMaterial_Click()

            Dim task2 As String



             task2 = "select * from TblPurchases order by [Material] "

    Me.Filter = "[Material]= '" & Me.CboMaterial & "'"
    Me.TxtTotal = Format(DCount("Material", "QueryMaterials"), "0")
    Me.RecordSource = ("QueryMaterials")



    End Sub
    'Second query
    Private Sub CmdSearchVendors_Click()

        Dim task As String

        task = "select * from TblPurchases order by [vendors] "

    Me.Filter = "[Vendor]= '" & Me.cbovendors & "'"
    Me.TxtTotal = Format(DCount("vendor", "Purchases Query"), "0")
    Me.RecordSource = ("Purchases Query")


    End Sub
```

the results that I am expecting is that for example I look for a material "cement" I get several records with three or four vendors for cement. I run the second query for one particular vendor but I get all transaction of that vendor, and not just the "cement" transaction of that vendor. I am expecting for example is if I select a vendor say("CitiHardware") I see all the items from "CitiHardware, OK fine. 
Now I pick a material say ("tools")that I want to isolate that are from "CitiHardware". what I get is all the vendors that I purchased "tools" from including CitiHardware. If I filter again "CitiHardware"  I get all Purchases."Tools" from CitiHardware is not isolated from the other records.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code. First of all you just filter the form and not the actual query. After you filtered the form you set the recordsource to the query itself again (without the filter).

There are several ways to achive what you want, this depends on your scenario. You can for example create the recordsource every time new based on your combo box selection.

```
...
Me.RecordSource = task & " WHERE " & Me.Filter

End Sub
```

Or you change the sql from the query:

```
Dim qdef as QueryDef
Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("YourQueryName")
qdef.SQL = "SELECT * FROM TblPurchases WHERE Material = 'MaterialString'"  
Me.Recordsource = "YourQueryName"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the advise and possible solution. However, opting for solution to create the recordsource every time  based on combo box selection produced a syntax error(missing operator in query expression[vendors]
WHERE[vendor] = "name of vendor"  this is how I wrote it out :                  Private Sub CmdSearchVendors_Click()
 Dim task As String      
 task = "select * from TblPurchases order by [vendors] "  
 Me.Filter = "[Vendor]= '" & Me.cbovendors & "'"
 Me.RecordSource = task & " WHERE " & Me.Filter
Me.TxtTotal = Format(DCount("vendor", "Purchases Query"), "0")        
End Sub

Comment: The `ORDER BY` clause comes at the end of the SQL string. Here is an example of a similar SQL string. `SELECT * FROM TblPurchases WHERE Vendor = '" & Me.cbovendors & "' ORDER BY Vendor`. And take care one time you use `vendor` the other `vendors`. This has to be the column name of the table.